# how to read/open password protected xlsx file in python

Tags: python, pandas, encryption, openpyxl, xlsx

ive successfully decrypted xlsx file using
 `cmd = "msoffcrypto-tool hello.xlsx decrypted.xlsx -p erh1"`
`os.system(cmd)`

but when i open the decrypted.xlsx using
`wb = load_workbook(inputFilePath, data_only=True)`

i get few warnings and and errors but it opens fine, i want to remove these errors

```
  File "/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 55, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(#REF!-40)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py", line 280, in parse_formatting
    cf = ConditionalFormatting.from_tree(element)
  File "/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/formatting/rule.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.val = val
  File "/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/formatting/rule.py", line 36, in __set__
    super(ValueDescriptor, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 67, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
  File "/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 57, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'float'>

  warn(msg)
/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py:300: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
/home/muhammadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py:300: UserWarning: Conditional Formatting extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
```

or is there any other way to decrypt xlsx using python ?
i used `msoffcrypto-tool`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a line that starts with `xlwb`, you should ensure that you have the proper code after it.

To open a protected file, you should have:

```
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, True, None, password)
```

That should hopefully work.